# Database value separation

Tags: java, database, resultset

I am developing a application to create chart. 
I have two types of Queries. 
**Type 1** returns only one Value[Double]
 **Type 2** returns Multiple values[Strings,Value]

I have included both sample results

> **Type 1:** 
>  **Hospital mortality rate**
>   
>  1.7879989 
>  
>     
>   **Type 2:**
>   
> **No of adverse drug reactions :** 
>  Adverse EventsAdverse drug reaction 56
> Adverse EventsAdverse drug reaction 67
> Adverse EventsAdverse post Transfusion reaction 31
> Adverse EventsAdverse post Transfusion reaction 32

I want to separate the string & values. Suggestions welcomed.
 My Query:

```
SELECT WMSNAB_MAIN_DESCRIPTION MAIN,WNSNAC_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION DETAIL,
COUNT(WMSNAD_PATIENT_ID) PID
FROM WMSNAB_INCIDENT_MASTER A,WMSNAC_INCIDENT_DETAIL B, 
WMSNAD_PATIENT_INCIDENTS C,WMSNAE_PAT_INCI_DET D
WHERE A.WMSNAB_MAIN_CODE       = B.WMSNAC_MAIN_CODE
AND B.WMSNAC_DETAIL_CODE     = D.WMSNAE_INCIDENT_DETAIL_CODE
AND C.WMSNAD_TRANS_ID = D.WMSNAE_TRANS_ID
AND TO_CHAR(C.WMSNAD_TRANS_DATE,'YYYY') = '2011'
AND A.WMSNAB_MAIN_CODE = 'A'
GROUP BY WMSNAB_MAIN_DESCRIPTION, WNSNAC_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION
UNION
SELECT WMSNAB_MAIN_DESCRIPTION MAIN,WNSNAC_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION DETAIL,
COUNT(WMSNAE_TRANS_ID) PID
FROM WMSNAB_INCIDENT_MASTER A,WMSNAC_INCIDENT_DETAIL B, WMSNAE_PAT_INCI_DET D
WHERE A.WMSNAB_MAIN_CODE       = B.WMSNAC_MAIN_CODE
AND B.WMSNAC_DETAIL_CODE     = D.WMSNAE_INCIDENT_DETAIL_CODE
AND TO_CHAR(D.WMSNAE_OCCURRED_DATE_TIME,'YYYY') = '2011'
AND A.WMSNAB_MAIN_CODE = 'A'
GROUP BY WMSNAB_MAIN_DESCRIPTION, WNSNAC_DETAIL_DESCRIPTION
```

Comment: Are the text elements in a separate column? Please post your current query. Also, which database are you using?

Comment: What have you tried? And what are you really asking: database structure and queries?

Comment: can you post the select statements you are using?

Comment: I am using Oracle 10g. this is my query: I will get the result in one/multiple line;

Comment: @SimeonVisser: Actually i want to separate the values and string for the input of chart.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample code

```
String s = "Adverse EventsAdverse drug reaction 56";
int number = Integer.valueOf(s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(' ')).trim());
```

Comment: I can directly parse if it is like as you have shown by the scenario is `String s = "Adverse EventsAdverse drug reaction 56 Adverse EventsAdverse drug reaction 67 Adverse EventsAdverse post Transfusion reaction 31 Adverse EventsAdverse post Transfusion reaction 32";`
what will you do now.?